# How to programmatically double apostrophes in custom label translations?

Tags: translation, customlabel, formatting, escape

I have a custom label which contains a couple of parameters:

```
Hello, {0} the other param is {1}.
```

I wish to output this value in a Visualforce Page like so:

```
<apex:variable var="firstParam" value="THE_NAME"/>
<apex:variable var="secondParam" value="SECOND_PARAM"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!$Label.Whatever}">
    <apex:param value="{!firstParam}"/>
    <apex:param value="{!secondParam}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

This of course outputs this:

```
Hello, THE_NAME, the other param is SECOND_PARAM.
```

So far so good. Now, if a translation for this custom label contains an apostrophe -- `Hello, {0}, it's the second param: {1}.` --, the string interpolation breaks like this:

```
Hello, THE_NAME, it's the second param: {1}.
```

I've discovered that I need to double the apostrophe -- `Hello, {0}, it''s the second param: {1}.` -- to make it work:

```
Hello, THE_NAME, it's the second param: SECOND_PARAM.
```

Escaping certain characters in strings is definitely a job for the computer rather than a translator.

**What's the Visualforce way to have the single apostrophes in a custom label escaped?**

I've tried to call a String replace method on the $Label.Whatever part, but this doesn't even compile. I also couldn't do `String($Label.Whatever)` to cast it, and I haven't been able to find any solution on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, you should be able to just do:

```
SUBSTITUTE($Label.Whatever, '\'', '\'\'')
```

However, I couldn't get `SUBSTITUTE` or `CONTAINS` to find the single quote characters until I created a new label with just that character.

```
SUBSTITUTE($Label.Whatever, $Label.SingleQuote, $Label.SingleQuote & $Label.SingleQuote)
```

---

The above approach is nice because it makes you independent of your controller. Additionally, you can write an `Apex Class` to help out as follows:

```
public class LabelServices
{
    public static String doubleSingleQuotes(String input)
    {
        return String.isBlank(input) ? input : input.replace('\'', '\'\'');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working, however it's a bit verbose. I wonder if there's a way to use some kind of static helper method which accepts a Custom Label name and returns the escaped value. I'm new to the Salesforce nomenclature so I'd be grateful for any tips as to what I should be looking for. :)

Comment: @Wabbitseason added some code but haven't tested yet.