# Can I extend apex:outputtext in a custom component?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, customlabel

`<apex:outputText>` accepts an arbitrary number of nested param tags, which is useful for inserting values in Custom Label translations.

Unfortunately there's a bug: if there's an apostrophe character in a translation it will prevent the substitution of values after the apostrophe. This can be circumvented by doubling the apostrophe ([How to programmatically double apostrophes in custom label translations?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121255/how-to-programmatically-double-apostrophes-in-custom-label-translations)), but using this wouldn't be DRY.

Is it possible to "extend" the outputText component so that inside a custom component the apostrophe doubling could be done automatically?

I'm looking for implementing something like this:

```
<c:translate label="{!$Label.myLabel}">
  <apex:param value="{!firstParam}"/>
  <apex:param value="{!secondParam}"/>
</c:translate>
```

I haven't been able to figure out yet how to access these parameters from the custom component's controller class.

Essentially this is what I'd like to shorten:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE($Label.myLabel, $Label.SingleQuote, $Label.SingleQuote & $Label.SingleQuote)}">
  <apex:param value="{!firstParam}"/>
  <apex:param value="{!secondParam}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Update: I'd like to emphasize that I want to accept **any number of parameters** for this component, as there can be no limit as to how many placeholders will the string contain which I need to translate.

Comment: Mostly just glad I found the double-quote workaround. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is for your component to just be:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute type="String" name="label" description="Label to output" />
    <apex:variable var="singlequote" value="{!$Label.SingleQuote}" />
    <apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(text, singlequote, singlequote & singlequote)}">
</apex:component>
```

Then in your page, you just do:

```
<c:translate label="{!$Label.myLabel}" / >
```

No inner params necessary.

Comment: How would I pass an arbitrary number of values to the Custom Label if not via params?